# Salesforce CLI Apex Data Loader Price Product Upload

Tags: salesforce, command-line-interface, product

I try to upload product price into salesforce using CLI apex data loader.
I have made an upsert request. Everything works, and the Product.sdl contains

```
price=Price
```

But the price is not upsert in standard price . Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you specify the correct PriceBook Id (i.e. the one for Standard Pricebook) in the Pricebook2 field?

Comment: Also, did it generate an errors file or do the command line invocations not do that? Can't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the CLI Apex data loader, but I have uploaded Products (Product2 object), Pricebooks (Pricebook2 object), and Pricebook entries (PricebookEntry object) before.

Make sure a "Standard Price Book" record exists in the Pricebook2 object.

Try inserting a PriceBookEntry with the Pricebook2Id field set to the Salesforce Id of the "Standard Price Book" record. Check the [data model](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_CSH.htm#sforce_api_erd_products.htm) for more information.